# Gradle Deployment to MarkLogic from WSL Fails with 'Permission denied: connect

Tags: gradle, windows-subsystem-for-linux, marklogic-10

I have set up MarkLogic 10.0-9.4 on Rocky Linux 9 within the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I'm attempting to deploy XQuery code to MarkLogic using Gradle. Here's the command I'm using from the Windows Command Prompt:

```
./gradlew -i -b deploy.gradle deploy -PmlHost="in-f6krxm3" -PdeployTestModule="false" -PreplicasCount=0 -PhostsInCluster=1 -PforestsPerHost=1 -PenvName="systest"
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\ravichoudhary\.gradle\native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 25040). The daemon log file: C:\Users\ravichoudhary\.gradle\daemon\6.7\daemon-25040.out.log
Starting 20th build in daemon [uptime: 3 hrs 25 mins 29.33 secs, performance: 100%]
Using 8 worker leases.
Watching the file system is disabled
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'D:\Project\Rocky\code\settings.gradle'.
Settings evaluated using settings file.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\Project\Rocky\code\deploy.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'code']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'code' using build file 'D:\Project\Rocky\code\deploy.gradle'.
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/github/http-builder-ng/http-plugin/io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin.gradle.plugin/0.1.1/io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin.gradle.plugin-0.1.1.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/net/saliman/properties/net.saliman.properties.gradle.plugin/1.4.6/net.saliman.properties.gradle.plugin-1.4.6.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/github/eerohele/saxon-gradle/com.github.eerohele.saxon-gradle.gradle.plugin/0.2.1/com.github.eerohele.saxon-gradle.gradle.plugin-0.2.1.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/marklogic/ml-gradle/com.marklogic.ml-gradle.gradle.plugin/4.1.0/com.marklogic.ml-gradle.gradle.plugin-4.1.0.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/gradle/plugin/com/marklogic/ml-gradle/4.1.0/ml-gradle-4.1.0.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/gradle/plugin/com/github/eerohele/saxon-gradle/0.2.1/saxon-gradle-0.2.1.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/gradle/plugin/io/github/http-builder-ng/http-plugin/0.1.1/http-plugin-0.1.1.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/marklogic/ml-app-deployer/4.1.0/ml-app-deployer-4.1.0.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/marklogic/marklogic-data-movement-components/2.2.0/marklogic-data-movement-components-2.2.0.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/marklogic/ml-javaclient-util/4.1.0/ml-javaclient-util-4.1.0.pom)]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/burgstaller/okhttp-digest/1.10/okhttp-digest-1.10.pom) 
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 : https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/burgstaller/okhttp-digest/2.3/okhttp-digest-2.3.pom)]  
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 21 properties from D:\Project\Rocky\code/gradle.properties                                             
PropertiesPlugin:apply Skipping D:\Project\Rocky\code/gradle-local.properties because it does not exist
PropertiesPlugin:apply Skipping C:\Users\ravichoudhary\.gradle/gradle.properties because it does not exist
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 0 properties from environment variables
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 0 properties from system properties
PropertiesPlugin:apply Loaded 6 properties from the command line

Initializing ml-gradle
Admin interface host: in-f6krxm3
Admin interface username: admin
Deploy privileges with the Configuration Management API (CMA): false
App name: iddn
App host: in-f6krxm3
App REST port: 8000
REST admin username: admin
App Services username: admin
Database names and replica counts: Extensions,0,Fab,0,last-login,0,Triggers,0
Databases and forest data directories: audit,/srv/MarkLogic/iddn/data2,iddn-batch,/srv/MarkLogic/iddn/data2,news-alerting,/srv/MarkLogic/news-alerting/data1
Module permissions: app-user,read,role-iddn-module-read,read,role-iddn-module-update,update,role-iddn-module-execute,execute,role-iddn-module-insert,insert
Additional binary extensions for loading modules: [.pdf]
Manage host: in-f6krxm3
Manage username: admin
Manage user with security role: admin
Initializing ManageClient with manage config of: [ManageConfig host: in-f6krxm3, port: 8002, username: admin, security username: admin]
Finished initializing ml-gradle

I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
Retrying connect
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
Retrying connect
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
Retrying connect

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
```

The error seems related to network connectivity. I've checked my network connection within WSL, and it seems to be working fine. I'm not sure what's causing the "Permission denied: connect" error.

Could someone please help me with this? it would be very appreciable.